# Django URLConf Not Resolving Properly

Tags: python, django

I'm following the Django introductory tutorial, and I'm running into a weird error. Or at least I think it's a weird error.
I'm on [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views), which is writing more views. I have, to the best I can tell, followed the tutorial to the letter.

My `/polls/urls.py` file looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, 
        name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

And `polls/views.py` looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")


def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question {question}.".format(question=question_id))


def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question {question}.".format(question=question_id)
    return HttpResponse(response)


def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question {question}.".format(question=question_id))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

And I've registered the urls in `my_project/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls', include("polls.urls"))
]
```

If I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls` I see the "hello world" message that I expect to see, but it I try looking up one of the questions, i.e. I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/` I see the following error message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in learning_django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns,  
in this order:

1. ^admin/
2. ^polls ^$ [name='index']
3. ^polls ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
4. ^polls ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$ [name='results']
5. ^polls ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$ [name='vote']

The current URL, polls/1/, didn't match any of these.
```

How is it possible that my url doesn't match number 3? It's such a basic regex.
[image]

Comment: try use  /polls/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `my_project/urls.py`, after `polls`, you missed `/`, change to :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/', include("polls.urls")) # add / after polls
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the Django `APPEND_SLASH` setting (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash) for documentation) or modify your URL pattern to make the `/` optional, e.g. like this:

`url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/?$', views.detail, name='detail'),`

Comment: Does the exact same thing.